# Is it true that lower 16 bits of CRC32 is CRC16?

Tags: java, crc, crc32, crc16

I just found that [this page](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4096290) is saying...

> I believe that CRC16 can be obtained from CRC32 by dropping the upper 16 bits.

Is it true?

Then is the lower 8 bits is for CRC8?

Comment: "CRC-16" isn't even well-defined; it identifies a whole family of related functions.

Comment: In a few words, no and no. The bug report you cited is from 1997, and the so-called review by someone who didn't know what he was talking about is from 2004.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The low bits of a CRC is not also a CRC. You can get another, shorter check value that way in a pinch, but it's not a CRC.